# Unexpected behaviour in bibliography using cleanthesis

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, overleaf, cleanthesis

I use cleanthesis in combination with overleaf (--> I guess version 0.4.0 from CTAN?) following the example document provided in the github repository. However, I struggle with unexpected behavior in the library.

1. On every item of my bibliography there is `(cit. on p. X)` at the end. I would very like to get rid of this, but have no idea how.
2. I want to sort my bibliography based on citation --> `bibsorting=none` but that does not work.
3. I tried to use my own biblatex options with `configurebiblatex=false`, but that does not work at all and cleanthesis then throws the error that the biblatex package is already loaded with different options

The only packages I load before cleanthesis are `[utf8]{inputenc}` and `[english]{babel}`. I would love to continue using cleanthesis, as I really enjoy the styling, and would appreciate any help!
*edit: Added MVP*

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,twoside=false,openright,parskip=full,chapterprefix=true,11pt,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,titlepage=on,captions=tableabove,draft=false]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}      

\usepackage[figuresep=colon,sansserif=false,hangfigurecaption=false,hangsection=true,hangsubsection=true,colorize=bw,colortheme=bluemagenta,configurebiblatex=true,bibsys=biber,bibfile=bib-refs,bibstyle=numeric,bibsorting=none,]{cleanthesis}

\begin{document}
\cite{hochreiter1997long}
\cite{devlin2018bert}

\printbibliography
```

Comment: (1) welcome to TSE, (2) As always on this site, please provide a full (but minumal) self contain document that others can copy and test as is. That is a lot easier to work with then having to stitch together a replica of your problem from the text you provided.

Answer (score 1):

The `cleanthesis` package issues the `biblatex` option `backref=true`.

You can set it to false by adding

```latex
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{backref=false}
```

after loading `cleanthesis`.